# Oracle - put sequence order in column salary where salary is null

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I put 1,2,3,4.... in sequence order in column salary where salary is null?? in oracle
I tried many things but could not find any accurate result

Comment: try to provide an example and what you try to do in order to help you

Answer (score 1):

```
select nvl(column,1) as columnName from yourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [ROWNUM](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm) pseudocolumn with `nvl` function:

```
select nvl(salary, ROWNUM ) from yourTable
```

> ROWNUM pseudocolumn returns a number indicating the order in which Oracle selects the row from a table or set of joined rows. The first row selected has a ROWNUM of 1, the second has 2, and so on.